# Any experience of using Naked Objects frameworks for .net?

Tags: .net, naked-objects

On first sight, [Naked Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naked_objects) look very promising in that they allow a full system with a basic UI to be created quickly, then refined.

Has anyone got real life experience using any of the .net Naked Objects frameworks?

How should I choose between the different Naked Objects frameworks?

Does anyone know of a .net Naked Objects frameworks that is open source, or at least does not have a per user licence cost when the finished application is deployed?

Comment: Naked Objects is now open source on .net, see  http://nakedobjects.codeplex.com/license

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is not an open source port of Naked Object to .net, the options at present seem to be:

- [Naked Object MVC](http://nakedobjects.net) (Naked Objects is now [open source](http://seenakedobjects.codeplex.com/license) on .net)
- [ASP.NET Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata) – A attempt by Microsoft to solve the same problem.  (free, no source code, [does not seem to be “actively promoted” by Microsoft](http://forums.asp.net/t/1604037.aspx?PageIndex=2ums.asp.net/t/1604037.aspx?PageIndex=2))

In both cases I have to ask myself how long will they be actively developed.

Comment: ASP.NET Dynamic Data totally misses the point. It is data-driven, not OO, leading to extremely bad models

Answer (score 3):

(FYI, we are very close to launching a brand new version of the product -  Naked Objects MVC.  This works with ASP.NET MVC 2 and gives you a complete HTML UI from the same domain objects, and then (if you really need to!) you can customise this UI using standard ASP.NET MVC patterns.

Best of all  -  from the point of view of your question  -  this will not have a per user license cost.  There will be a per-developer cost (not yet fixed, but realistically priced) and there will be a free time-unlimited evaluation version (which runs locally but not on a remote IIS Server).

If you're interested in trying this out, please get in touch with me (rpawson at nakedobjects.net)

Comment: given how great the lockin will be, I can't see anyone going for this without full source code.  Hence I think a option source framework is what is needed to get Naked Objects into common useage.

Answer (score 3):

Naked Objects MVC does include (in the licensed version) the source code of the MVC UI part  -  though it does not include the source code of the underlying Naked Objects for .NET framework.  The latter is in use in a big way in the Irish government.  FYI, part of the commitment to that client is that in the event that our company is no longer able/willing to actively develop and support the product, then it will automatically revert to an open source license  -  I think that's as fair a commitment as one can make.

Also, FYI, though Dynamic Data has some similarities, it is not really the same thing:  it does not expose object behaviour in the form of actions.  This is a much bigger deal than it might sound.  I agree that Microsoft does not appear to be actively promoting DD now, though.  There was an attempt to re-implement DD within ASP.NET MVC, but that also has since been removed from CodePlex.

Answer (score 0):

Ian, the source is available at http://sourceforge.net/projects/nakedobjects/ but it's only Java. But I guess you could run it through Microsoft's Java to .Net converter.